# How to `go test` all tests in my project?

Tags: testing, go

The `go test` command covers `*_test.go` files in only one dir.

I want to `go test` the whole project, which means the test should cover all `*_test.go` files in the dir `./` and every children tree dir under the dir `./`.

What's the command to do this?

Answer (score 573, accepted):

This should run all tests in current directory and all of its subdirectories:

```
$ go test ./...
```

This should run all tests for given specific directories:

```
$ go test ./tests/... ./unit-tests/... ./my-packages/...
```

This should run all tests with import path prefixed with `foo/`:

```
$ go test foo/...
```

This should run all tests import path prefixed with `foo`:

```
$ go test foo...
```

This should run all tests in your $GOPATH:

```
$ go test ...
```

Comment: FYI in zsh, the bare `...` in the last example must be escaped, IE `go test \...`

Comment: When I am trying to run all the tests in subdir I am getting `go: warning: "subdir/..." matched no packages`

Comment: @zzzz how to run tests for specific folders? say "go test foo... bar...?

Comment: `go test ./...` is really a great command!. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Don't forget `-v` parameter if you want to see outputs of successful tests too.

Comment: Where is "./..." documented? It's hard to search on Google

Answer (score 86):

[From Go 1.9 onwards](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#vendor-dotdotdot), use

```
go test ./...
```

In Go 1.6 through 1.8, the `./...` matched also the [`vendor` directory](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories). To skip vendored packages, you'd use

```
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
```

Sources: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11659, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14417, https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/2366, @nickgrim's comment.

Comment: As easy as this solution looks, it makes it much more complicated for people on Windows (I'm not but some of my team mates are) to run this. The beauty of Go running native on each platform without the need for a Makefile is great.

Comment: Worth pointing out that [as of Go 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#vendor-dotdotdot) `./...` no longer matches the `./vendor/` directory, so you can run all of your tests and none of the vendor-tests with `go test ./...`

Answer (score 16):

> Folder Structure

```
ProjectName/folderName1/file_test.go
ProjectName/folderName2/file1_test.go
ProjectName/folderName3/file2_test.go
```

> go test command Command

```
   ProjectName$ go test -v ./...
    ProjectName$ go test  ./...
    ProjectName$ go test -cover ./...
```

> Coverage Report for the Entire Project

```
ok      ProjectName/folderName1 10%
ok      ProjectName/folerName2  90%
ok      ProjectName/folerName2  85%
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking out several answers on the topic (SO and elsewhere) the go-way seems to be using tools already provided (e.g. by OS).

For multi-module projects most find-based oneliners or 'go list ...' solutions seem to fall short so I just ended up creating [bash runner script](https://github.com/istonikula/realworld-go/commit/e349dcd3066653550104b23b57cf4324c96d06c9) (disclaimer: in WIP state, if the previous link does not work, check [this](https://github.com/istonikula/realworld-go))