# Golang tests in sub-directory

Tags: unit-testing, go, build

I want to create a package in Go with tests and examples for the package as subdirectories to keep the workspace cleaner. Is this possible and if so how?

All the documentation always puts the testing code in the same place as the other code, is this better in some way or just convention?

Comment: Note: `go test ./...` will run tests on the current folder *and* all subfolders. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21725603/6309)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`go test\` all testings in my project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353016/how-to-go-test-all-testings-in-my-project)

Comment: i was thinking the same thing. having trouble putting tests n a seperate dir because diretor on the same level have sub dirs.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

Note that you *can* run `go test` "recursively": you need to **list all the packages you want to test**.

If you are in the root folder of your Go project, type:

```
go test ./...
```

The '`./...`' notation is described in the section "[Description of package lists](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_package_lists)" of the "[command `go`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)":

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "`...`" wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes.
>
> Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the `GOPATH` trees with names matching the patterns.
>
> As a special case, `x/...` matches `x` as well as `x`'s subdirectories.
> For example, `net/...` expands to `net` and packages in its subdirectories.

---

If you keep your `_test.go` files in a subfolder, the '`go test ./...`' command will be able to pick them up.
But:

- you will need to prefix your exported variables and functions (used in your tests) with the name of your package, in order for the test file to be able to access the package exported content.
- you wouldn't access non-exported content.

That being said, I would still prefer to keep the `_test.go` file right beside the main source file: it is easier to find.

---

2022: For code coverage:

```
go test -coverpkg=./... ./...
```

See "[How to plot Go test coverage over time](https://osinet.fr/go/en/articles/plotting-go-test-coverage/)" from [Frédéric G. MARAND](https://osinet.fr/a-propos) and [`fgmarand/gocoverstats`](https://gitlab.com/fgmarand/gocoverstats) to produce aggregate coverage statistics for CI integration of Go projects.

Also, [`go-cover-treemap.io`](https://go-cover-treemap.io/) is fun.

---

March 2023: As documented in "[Code coverage for Go integration tests](https://go.dev/blog/integration-test-coverage)":

> With the 1.20 release, Go’s coverage tooling is no longer limited to package tests, but supports collecting profiles from larger integration tests.

Example:

```golang
$ go build -cover -o myprogram.exe myprogram.go
$ mkdir somedata
$ GOCOVERDIR=somedata ./myprogram.exe
I say "Hello, world." and "see ya"
$ ls somedata
covcounters.c6de772f99010ef5925877a7b05db4cc.2424989.1670252383678349347
covmeta.c6de772f99010ef5925877a7b05db4cc
```

See [Go 1.20 Cover](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#cover).

---

As noted by [kbolino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814422/kbolino) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200235/golang-tests-in-sub-directory/21725603#comment133586385_21725603):

> You can put your tests in a separate package without putting them in a separate directory.
> Test files for package foo can be in package `foo_test` and still be in the same directory, while also *not* having any access to unexported (private) members of package `foo`.

Comment: Some might argue non-access to private stuff is normal black-box testing and better. Regarding having to qualify public symbols, you can always import _ "...".

Comment: I found that `go test ./...` doesn't work well if (a) you have tests in a separate folder, and (b) you want to measure code coverage. For some reason, code coverage misses the package under test

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Interresting. I doscovered https://go-cover-treemap.io/ recently. Also https://osinet.fr/go/en/articles/plotting-go-test-coverage/ can help.

Comment: i had to add `-coverpkg=./...` and it worked!

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Do you mean as in `go test -coverpkg=./... ./...`? Or just `go test -coverpkg=./...`?

Comment: It is probably worth noting that you can put your tests in a separate _package_ without putting them in a separate _directory_. Test files for package `foo` can be in package `foo_test` and still be in the same directory, while also not having any access to unexported (private) members of package `foo`.

Answer (score 25):

**EDITED**

Built on VonC's answer,

This answer is valid in `go1.11`. No yet tested in upper `go` versions.

For those of you who like to keep their tests in a sub-folder, say `test`, then running

```
go test ./...
```

will attempt to run tests in *every* folder, even those that do not contain any test, thus having a `?` in the subsequent report for non-test folders.

Running

```
go test ./.../test
```

instead will target only your `test` folders, thus having a clean report focused on your tests folders only.

**CAUTION**

Please be mindful that using test sub-folders will prevent coverage report computation. The phylosophy of go is to leave test files in the package folders.

Comment: dear anna, please explain what does not work? and what is your version of go? what are you trying to do? I realized afterwards that this method does not allowed to compute code coverage, which is a pitty. Is this what you mean?

Comment: `go test ./.../test` returns `go: warning: "./.../test" matched no packages` // does not only target test folders. go version go1.13 darwin/amd64

Comment: I don't know about `go1.13`. I should precise that this answer my answer is valid in `go1.11`.

Comment: @Madeo, this would make sens, because golang does not encourage segregation of tests and code. The anomaly was to allow it in previous versions.

Comment: @avi.elkharrat and in fact I have decided to not purse this approach anymore, even though I liked to keep my tests into a separate package/folder =(

Comment: @Madeo, same here dude. I like the java / maven style better, but it does not work like this in `Go`. Code coverage is more important than personal preferences, i guess.

Comment: so go seems still broken as of 2022, i would like to segregate my tests but can't seem to find a good way to do so

Comment: Run `go test ./tests/...` to run go test only within `tests/` folder.

Answer (score 22):

Put your tests alongside your code in the same directory in a file called `file_test.go` where "file" is the name of the source code file you're testing. This is convention and I've found it to be best in my own experience.

If the `go test` tool isn't quite automated enough for you, you might look into **[GoConvey](http:///goconvey.co)**, which has a web UI that will automatically update and run traditional Go tests as well as GoConvey tests (which are based on behavior, and are more self-documenting than traditional Go tests).

Comment: GoConvey is awesome (and I am waiting for the new UI with high anticipation). I am using it in my current project as in https://github.com/VonC/asciidocgo/blob/master/abstractNode_test.go , for instance). However, `go test` can also work for subfolders. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21725603/6309)

Comment: Right you are. In fact, it's probably more relevant than my answer for this question.

Answer (score -7):

I normally don't do test, but you can group your file into directories and use import like

`import "./models"` if is one level out
`import "../models` if is one level out and one level in

For example, for:
`./models/todo.go`
`./test/todo_test.go`

to test `todo.go` from `todo_test.go`, 
your import in the `todo_test.go` will be

`import "../models"`

Comment: This method of importing the code only works for exposed functions. It does not seem to behave like they are in the same package even thought you explicitly put them in the same package. So this solution does not really solve the problem for unit testing.