# go build works but go test does not

Tags: go

Below is my project structure:

```
/user/home/go/src/github.com/my_go_proj
                                       /main.go
                                       /mypackage
                                                 /service.go
                                                 /service_test.go

GOPATH points to /user/home/go
cd /user/home/go/src/github.com/my_go_proj
go build ---> This works and creates the `my_go_proj` executable.
go test
?       github.com/my_go_proj   [no test files]
go test github.com/my_go_proj/mypackage
go build gopkg.in/tomb.v2: no buildable Go source files in 
FAIL    github.com/my_go_proj/mypackage [build failed]

go test ./...
?       github.com/my_go_proj   [no test files]
go build gopkg.in/tomb.v2: no buildable Go source files in 
FAIL    github.com/my_go_proj/mypackage [build failed]
```

How do I run `go test` to run the service_test.go test inside mypackage?

**Update:** updated the behaviour for `go test ./...`

Comment: does `go test ./...` work? (and what does `go build gopkg.in/tomb.v2` have to do with this?)

Comment: Potential duplicate of [How to `go test` all testings in my project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353016/) and [Golang tests in sub-directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200235/).

Comment: I have no idea where gopkg.in/tomb.v2 is coming from. `go test ./...` also did not work.

Comment: Something is trying to build "gopkg.in/tomb.v2", have you tried getting that dependency?

Comment: @MatthewRankin It is not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the directory structure. My project source should be in `$GOPATH`. But it was inside `$GOPATH/src`.

**Incorrect** /user/home/go/**src**/github.com/my_go_proj 
**Correct** /user/home/go/github.com/my_go_proj

Answer (score 1):

To test all subdirectories use:

```
$ go test ./...
```

From the [Relative import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths) section of the [Command go](https://golang.org/doc/cmd) documentation:

> Relative patterns are also allowed, like `go test ./...` to test all subdirectories. See 'go help packages' for details on the pattern syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have the answer to the title question of "`go build` works but `go test` doesn't", since I think many people get here because of that title and not of their directory structure.

What happens is that `go-build` and `go-test` may have different compilation options. For example, a `go-build` may tolerate warnings but `go-test` doesn't.

The problem here is that in a typical project you have many tests *(so typically inside your build system such as Meson or Make you have a call `go test […list of tests goes here…]`)*. In which case the warning prints may appear at the wrong location, such as at the beginning of the `go-test`. So you will see a wall of text *(especially if you added a `-v`)*, but the actual error will not be inside the text group relevant to the failing test.

What you can do here *(besides of course peeking at the beginning of the log now that you know the problem)* is you can run `go test go-specific-path/to/test`, which will only run that test alone so you will definitely see what's failing.

So, given the OP's case: instead of running `go test […list of tests goes here…]` just run that one test:

```hs
go test github.com/my_go_proj/mypackage
go build gopkg.in/tomb.v2: no buildable Go source files in
FAIL    github.com/my_go_proj/mypackage [build failed]
```