# How to `go test` in sub-directories only tests matching a given pattern?

Tags: go, testing

In my project I have multiple packages and sub-directories. In top directory, I can run `go test ./...` and it runs all the tests in all sub-directories. I have been reading for quite some time on how test only tests matching a given pattern or test name but unable to find a solution. By going through these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935965/how-to-run-test-cases-in-a-specified-file) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353016/how-to-go-test-all-tests-in-my-project) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200235/golang-tests-in-sub-directory) and [godocs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Description_of_package_lists)) I thought I could use this:

```
go test ./... -run mypattern
```

to run tests matching *mypattern* but for me it runs all the tests. For now I am using a combination of *cd*, *find* and *grep* to run tests matching my criteria.

You can try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/grafana/grafana-plugin-sdk-go.git  
> go test -run TestJSON  
=== RUN   TestJSONNotice
=== RUN   TestJSONNotice/notice_with_severity_and_text
--- PASS: TestJSONNotice (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestJSONNotice/notice_with_severity_and_text (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestJSON
=== RUN   TestJSON/json.Unmarshal_and_json.Marshal
=== RUN   TestJSON/json.Unmarshal_and_json.Marshal/Should_run_without_error
=== RUN   TestJSON/json.Unmarshal_and_json.Marshal/Should_create_equal_data
--- PASS: TestJSON (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestJSON/json.Unmarshal_and_json.Marshal (0.00s)
        --- PASS: TestJSON/json.Unmarshal_and_json.Marshal/Should_run_without_error (0.00s)
        --- PASS: TestJSON/json.Unmarshal_and_json.Marshal/Should_create_equal_data (0.00s)
PASS
ok      github.com/grafana/grafana-plugin-sdk-go/data   0.016s

> cd data

> go test -run *TestJSON*  
  zsh: no matches found: *TestJSON*  

> go test -run ^TestJSON*  
  zsh: no matches found: ^TestJSON*
    
> go test -v -cover --short -race  ./... -run ^TestFloatAt*  
  zsh: no matches found: ^TestFloatAt*
```

Can someone please tell me how test only tests matching a given pattern or test name?

Comment: It does work (though I would suggest not putting a flag after the arguments, since most go programs do not parse them). Please show a [mre] which demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Passing tests do not print anything, are you really certain they are _not_ being run?

Comment: It seems to work fine on my machine. Can you share the exact value for "mypattern", and can you reproduce this in a public GitHub repo?

Comment: @Raaka you need to put the expression in quotes, your shell is trying to parse it as a file wildcard, which you can tell because you're getting a shell error and not a go test error.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian that's how I started my day today:

10094  8/6/2021 09:07  go test -run "^TestLoad$" 


It was a combination of not using -v flag and quotes at some later point. The output from go didn't help either, it says "[no tests to run]" for the test cases left out. As I am new to the repo that I am working on I thought it was due to missing or no test cases present in the repo. Coming from node didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing regular expression that fits name of your test should run matched tests...

for examples:

```
go test -v -cover --short -race  ./... -run ^TestError*
```

runs different tests that's start with TestError in the project...

```
?       github.com/user/project/internal/rabbitmq       [no test files]
=== RUN   TestErrorMiddleware
    printer.go:54: GET http://localhost:45678/surprise
⇨ http server started on [::]:45678
{"error":{"code":"EXPECTED","status":418},"level":"warning","msg":"expected: here's tea","time":"2021-08-06T17:25:58+03:00"}
--- PASS: TestErrorMiddleware (0.01s)
PASS
coverage: 54.8% of statements
ok      ithub.com/user/project/internal/datadog        3.725s  coverage: 70.6% of statements
?       github.com/user/project/internal/ftp    [no test files]
?       github.com/user/project/internal/mongo  [no test files]
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
coverage: 0.0% of statements
ok      github.com/user/project/postgres       3.704s  coverage: 0.0% of statements [no tests to run]
ok      github.com/user/project/escrow  7.784s  coverage: 0.0% of statements [no tests to run]
=== RUN   TestError
--- PASS: TestError (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestErrorHandling
--- PASS: TestErrorHandling (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 70.6% of statements
...
```

what you targeting is a name of the test (function name that starts with `Test`)